# Scanner does not continue to read multiple lines of file for login function

Tags: button, javafx, while-loop

I have a login button that reads two lines of text from a text.file the first line is the username and the second line is the password. There a multiple usernames and passwords in the text file however the code only works for the first pair.

```
btLogin.setOnAction(e -> {
   boolean grantAccess = false;
        String userName = tfUsername.getText();
        String password = tfPassword.getText();
    File f = new File("users.txt");
    try { 
    Scanner read = new Scanner(f);
    int lineNo=0;
    while(read.hasNextLine()) {
        lineNo++;
    String loginInfo = read.nextLine();

    if ((lineNo == 1)&& (loginInfo.equals(userName))) {
        continue;
    }
    else if ((lineNo == 2) && (loginInfo.equals(password))) {
        grantAccess=true;
        break;
    }
    else {
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the test file.

Comment: You `break` out of the loop in every condition except the first `if` statement. So even after reading two lines, if the username and password don't match, the final `else` breaks out of the loop.

Comment: (In fact, if the username doesn't match on the first line, you `break` out of the loop immediately.)